# .Net textbox is null when a "submit" link is clicked

Tags: asp.net, binding

Good day,

I have a problem in a .NET page where I am using an asp:textbox in combination with an OnClick action on a link button.

What happens is that after text has been entered into the textbox, if you directly click on the link button, more often than not the textbox is considered to be null.

If you click off the text box first then click the link, all is well and the save function performed by the link button proceeds as expected.

My assumption is that there is a lifecycle event that is being missed, or not applied which is not binding the text to the textbox for use in the codebehind when the link button is clicked.

The question is, what can i do to enforce that binding short of doing something like adding an onkeypress event to the textbox to force a postback.

There must be a more elegant solution.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have initializations on your textbox inside Page_Load event? If so, use IsPostBack=false and put the initialization inside.

```
If IsPostBack =False Then
  TextBox1.text=""
End If
```

Comment: I actually found that i had missed assigning a value from that textbox to a detatched entity before it was persisted, and i was distracted by the null so i didnt notice that it was actually an insert error on a field which didnt accept nulls.